# Multiply two list of different sizes element wise without using libraries in python

Tags: python

```
#create a simple list in python
#list comprehension
x = [i for i in range(100)]
print (x)

#using loops
squares = []
for x in range(10):
    squares.append(x**2)

print (squares)

multiples = k*[z for z in x] for k in squares
```

So in the last line of code I am trying to multiply both the lists. the problem is the lists are not of the same side and k*[z for z in x] this part is also incorrect.

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean by multiply element-wise when the lists are different lengths. What output do you expect?

Comment: can you give us an example for inputs and outputs?

Comment: seriously, just hardcode a [1,2,3,4] and [1,4,9] and write out your expected result.  large lists contribute no clarity whatsoever.

Comment: two lists
[1,2,3,4,5] and [1,2]: now I want to multiply these two lists. Knowing the fact that one list might be larger than the other, the code should not give an error and the new list produced should have the length of the smaller list. I hope this clarifies the confusion

I know I can hard code it but Im looking for a generic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problems with iteration, I suggest anyone to check [Loop Like A Native](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html) by Ned Batchelder and [Looping like a Pro](https://archive.org/details/pycon-2017-looping) by David Baumgold

## Option 1

If you want to multiply them as far as the shortest list goes, `zip` is your friend:

```
multiples = [a * b for a, b in zip (x, squares)]
```

## Option 2

If you want a matrix with the product, then you can do it like this

```
result = [
    [a * b for a in x]
    for b in squares
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what the desired output would be. As the function stands now, you would have a list of lists, where the first element has 100 elements, the second one 400, the third 900, and so on.

- One thing that's strange: The expression `[z for z in x]` defines a list that is identical to x. So, you might just write `k*x`
- If you want to multiply the elements of both lists, you would have to write `[[k*z for z in x] for k in squares]`. This would lead to a list of 10 lists of 100 elements (or a 10x100-matrix) containing the products of your lists.
- If you want to have one list of length 100 in the end that holds some kind of products, you will have to think about how to proceed with the shorter list.
- EDIT: Or if you want to multiply them as far as possible until you reach the end of the shorter list, FRANCOIS CYRIL's solution is an elegant way to do so.

Comment: The third point, I want one list of length 100 in the end that holds some kind of products

Comment: So, what should these 100 elements be? `[squares[0]*x[0], squares[1]*x[1], ..., squares[0]*x[10], squares[1]*x[12],...]` or `[squares[0]*x[0], squares[0]*x[1], ..., squares[1]*x[10], squares[1]*x[11],...]`. Or any other rule of allocation?

Comment: For example: 
list-1: [1,2,3,4,5]
list-2: [1,2,3]

now multiply:

list-1[0] * list-2[0].....list-1[2]*list-2[2]

The output list is of length 3 because the shorter list length is three.

The multiplication stops at the length of the shorter list.

I'm having trouble in devising a generic code.

Comment: But what do you WANT the two remaining elements to be in this example? Products of which elements?

Answer (score -1):

You can loop on each array to multiply element by element at the same position in a result array:

```
i = 0
arrayRes = []
while i < min (len(array1),len(array2)):
    arrayRes.append(array1[i]*array2[i])
    i+=1
```

Or do you prefer to multiply them, matrix way?

```
x = 0
y = 0
arrayRes = []
while x < len(array1):
    arrayRes.append([])
    while y < len(array2):
        arrayRes[x].append(array1[x]*array2[y])
        y+=1
    x+=1
```

Comment: don't loop over the indexes, but use `zip` for the first part. The second part can way clearer be solved with list expressions